# Add data to angular $http request that will be returned in the response

Tags: angularjs

I need to add some data to each response I send via $http in angular that will be in the response. In other works I'm trying to add an 'id' to the request because when the response is returned I need to associate it with the correct object that sent it. Is this possible? If so how would I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

use interceptors, I'm quoting from the documentation:

> For purposes of global error handling, authentication, or any kind of
>   synchronous or asynchronous pre-processing of request or
>   postprocessing of responses, it is desirable to be able to intercept
>   requests before they are handed to the server and responses before
>   they are handed over to the application code that initiated these
>   requests.

```
$provide.factory('myHttpInterceptor', function($q, dependency1, dependency2) {
  return {

    'request': function(config) {
      config.id = generateId(); //or a timestamp maybe?
      return config;
    },


    'response': function(response) {
      // do something on success
      return response;
    }

  };
});
```

then add your

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('myHttpInterceptor');
```